# What is the class of "if/unless" etc

Tags: ruby, oop, irb

Considering that everything in Ruby is an object and we can open irb and type things like `4.class` and `"Text".class` to see from which class an object is, why do `if.class` and `unless.class` give no return value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Considering that everything in Ruby is an object

That depends on your definition of "*object*" and every-"*thing*". "*Object*" can mean "*entity that can be manipulated by the program*" (which I will call **object** from now on), or "*value that is a member of the object system*" (which I will call `Object` from now on).

In Ruby, everything that can be manipulated by the program (i.e. every **object**) is also an `Object`, i.e. an instance of a class. This is unlike Java, for example, where *primitives* can be manipulated by the program (i.e. are **objects** in that sense of the word), but aren't `Objects`. In Ruby, this distinction doesn't exist: every **object** is an `Object` and every `Object` is also an **object**.

However, there are *things* in the language, which *cannot* be manipulated by the program and which aren't instances of a class, i.e. they are neither **object** s nor `Object`s. These are, for example, methods, variables, syntax, parameter lists, argument lists, keywords.

Note: you can use Ruby's reflection API to give you an object that *represents* a method or a parameter list, but that object is only a proxy, it is not the real thing.

So, when we say "*everything is an object*", what we really mean is that "every **object** is an `Object`", i.e. that everything which can be manipulated by the program is also a member of the object system, or in other words, there are no values outside of the object system (unlike primitives in Java). We do *not* mean that everything that exists in the language can also be manipulated at runtime by the program.

> why do `if.class` and `unless.class` give no return value

Well, first off, even *if* `if` *were* an object, those don't do what you think they do: when you say something like `foo` in Ruby, it means either "dereference the local variable `foo`" or "call the method `foo` with `self` as the implicit receiver and no argument list". So,

```
if.class
```

would either give you the class of the object *referenced* by the local variable `if` or the class of the object *returned* by the method `if`, but *never* the class of `if` itself.

But the `if` control flow keyword isn't an object, anyway (neither an **object** nor an `Object`) because keywords and control flow aren't objects in Ruby.

In the book [*The Ruby Programming Language* by Matz and David Flanagan](http://Amazon.Com/dp/0596516177/) it says on page 2:

> every value is an object

Note, it doesn't say every-*thing*, only every *value*.

See also the question [Is variable is object in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/a/8385471/2988/)

Comment: Very good explanation, included that linked question. Thanks! To add more to confuse, at http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html `if` is listed as a method of Object class but if you click at keywords.rb it says "Yes, I KNOW that they aren't methods. I've just put them in that format to produce the familiar RDoc output.". So `if` is just a keyword although it could have been made as an object and keywords don't act as objects.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are language keywords and not objects. In general, everything you can assign to a variable is an object.

To be technically correct: keywords such as `unless` *might* have a class that is used by compiler/interpreter (depends on an actual implementation), but you, as a language user, don't have any even remotely practical use for it and so it's not exposed to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.9.2-p320 :019 > def meth
1.9.2-p320 :020?>   'meth'
1.9.2-p320 :021?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.2-p320 :022 >
```

If you observe the question mark and the indentation, when IRB detects something that needs continuation, it indents.

```
1.9.2-p320 :022 > if.class
1.9.2-p320 :023?>   ...
1.9.2-p320 :028?>   end
SyntaxError: (irb):22: syntax error, unexpected '.'
if.class
   ^
(irb):28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

1.9.2-p320 :045 > if.if
1.9.2-p320 :046?>   end
SyntaxError: (irb):45: syntax error, unexpected '.'
if.if
   ^

1.9.2-p320 :060 > str = 'abc'
 => "abc" 
1.9.2-p320 :061 > str.
1.9.2-p320 :062 >   length
 => 3 
1.9.2-p320 :063 >
1.9.2-p320 :083 > if
1.9.2-p320 :084 >     str
1.9.2-p320 :085?>   puts '>>>'
1.9.2-p320 :086?>   end
>>>
 => nil 
1.9.2-p320 :087 >
```

As you can see, IRB does not immediately answer, even if there is an obvious mistake such as sending a message to a reserved word. The ? is the sign that it is waiting for the rest of the statement.